# How to disable copy paste text in flash chat window

Tags: flash, actionscript, copy-paste, blocking

I am use flash based live video chat application in my site and someone make text flood in chat . How can I disable paste text in `TextBox` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you would have to listen for the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN event, and in your handler, determine if the control key and the "V" keycode are in the event.  If so, you would have to invoke "event.preventDefault()".  Something like this.

```
public function stopCopying(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var controlActive:Boolean = event.controlKey;
    // Is the control buttton down?
    if( controlActive )
    {
        //[v keycode = 86][1]
        if( event.keyCode == 86 )
        {
           event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty much the best I can do off the top of my head, I haven't ever used this in practice.

Comment: @Jonathan I've given you the answer.